# String does not match regex

Tags: java, regex

I want the regex to check if there is a "word" ( [a-zA-Z0-9] ) and if there is a bracket there has to be something like (id = [0-9]+ ) after that one of these six "relations" followed by another word. There has to be at least one whitespace between the words and the relation. There can be more whitespaces between the words and the relation and between (,),id,= and number. The three Strings are just there to shorten the lines.

This code always prints false no matter what I try:

```
String first = "\\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\s\\(\\sid\\s=\\s[0-9]+\\s\\))?\\s+";
String second = "(contains|contained-in|part-of|has-part|successor-of|predecessor-of)\\s+";
String third = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\s\\(\\sid\\s=\\s[0-9]+\\s\\))?\\s";
Pattern linePattern = Pattern.compile(first + second + third);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "apple(id=107) contained-in tree";
    Matcher matcher = linePattern.matcher(a);
    boolean matches = matcher.matches();
    System.out.println(matches);
}
```

Comment: ah and i know that i should declare them static.  I did so in my actual code, but this is just to make it easier to read. :)

Comment: Your pattern starts with `\\s` while your example doesn't start with a space.

Comment: and how can i re write it so that it accepts if there are zero to infinity spaces?

Comment: `\\s*` for zero to infinity spaces

Comment: now i rewrote it to
 ` String first = "\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\s*\\(\\sid\\s*=\\s*[0-9]+\\s*\\))?\\s+";
    String second = "(contains|contained-in|part-of|has-part|successor-of|predecessor-of)\\s+";
    String third = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\s*\\(\\s*id\\s*=\\s*[0-9]+\\s*\\))?\\s*";
    Pattern linePattern = Pattern.compile(first + second + third);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "centos7(id=107) contained-in operatingsystem";
        Matcher matcher = linePattern.matcher(a);
        boolean matches = matcher.matches();
        System.out.println(matches);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `\s*`:

`\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\s*\(\s*id\s*=\s*[0-9]+\s*\))?\s*(contains|contained-in|part-of|has-part|successor-of|predecessor-of)\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\s*\(\s*id\s*=\s*[0-9]+\s*\))?\s*`

```
Pattern linePattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\s*\(\\s*id\\s*=\\s*[0-9]+\\s*\\))?\\s*(contains|contained-in|part-of|has-part|successor-of|predecessor-of)\\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\s*\\(\\s*id\\s*=\\s*[0-9]+\\s*\\))?\\s*");
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make it a series of OR'd regexes?

Comment: @beresfordt: Yeah, I was too quick. I updated the regex pattern.